# Execution default-testResources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I was doing a project at work on a PC there, when I got home I tried to open it on my PC and I ended up encountering two errors in line 5 of the pom.xml file, my PC already gave an error when installing the new ones versions of eclipse, now this is giving error in my work project, I hope someone help me please.

error 1:

```
Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'testResources' (or one of its required components) from the plugin
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0'
(org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources)
```

error 2:

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: 
Unable to load the mojo 'resources' (or one of its required components) from the plugin
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0'
(org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources:default-resources:process-resources)
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The errors indicate that a dependency has not been downloaded correctly ...first I recommend to run your build with `mvn clean package -U` furthermore check that output about some issues/warnings during the build (please do on plain command line)..

Comment: I tried this command and ended up getting this error:  `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project demo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: Unable to load the mojo 'resources'`

Comment: Is there any output before those errors? I suppose so?

Comment: it only gives a Scanning for projects,  `[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo`
Sorry the text is messed up, I still don't know how to work the site properly

Comment: Try to delete your local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` and rebuild...redirect the output of your build into a file...

Comment: I did it and it kept giving the same error